# How to check the input image is matched with the cropped face pic or not?

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to check whether a given image is matched with a cropped face image. I tried to crop the face from the image using OpenCV Python. Now i want to check if the input image is a match with the cropped face or not. What methods can I use with OpenCV to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For sufficiently small (and not scientifically accurate) purposes, you could use OpenCV's  [template matching.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

[Feature extraction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) and matching may give you more accurate results in many cases. Face detector comes in as a part of OpenCV. Face recognition, however, is a much larger problem altogether.

Comment: I can't get u clearly... plz can u explain briefly... In python opencv am asking..

Comment: Which part? Look at the links. In template matching, you have a reference image (a template), and you look for regions very similar to it in your image of interest. Or you could extract local features from your reference image, and match them in your image.

Comment: cv.MatchTemplate(image, templ, result, method)--->>>> is the syntax is enough for to match it... in that, method is ref for ??

Comment: It will serve basic purposes. You've to be aware of what `method` is and what to do with `result`.

Comment: Depends on the method you use.

Comment: Here is a good post on how to perform template matching with OpenCV. http://machinelearningmastery.com/using-opencv-python-and-template-matching-to-play-wheres-waldo/

Comment: I want to know the accuracy of matching face... how to do that.. anybody suggest me...